# PDO Firebird select stored procedure

Tags: pdo, firebird

Is it normal that you have to select the same number of columns in the prepare statement as input parameters?

For example:

```
$stmt->prepare("select test1 from SP_TEST(?,?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1,$test1);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$test1);
...
```

That doesn't work..

The moment I add another column in my select statement it works:

```
...
$stmt->prepare("select test1,test2 from SP_TEST(?,?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1,$test1);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$test1);
...
```

Comment: Seems like a bug to me , please open a ticket at https://bugs.php.net/